# Error while trying to create circular reveal: IllegalStateException: cannot start this animation on a detached view

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

So, I'm experimenting trying to create a circular reveal on API level 21 on a TextView but I keep getting this error. At first I thought it had something to do with the lifecycle of the fragment I was attempting it but then I just tried the same thing in an activity and it still wouldn't work.

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        w.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#0277bd"));


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);



        int a = (tv.getLeft() + tv.getRight()) / 2;
        int b = (tv.getTop() + tv.getBottom()) / 2;

        int radius = tv.getWidth();

        Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(tv, a, b, 0, radius);

        anim.start();





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

It's still early days so I can't really find any answers about this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're getting the error because the view you passed in hasn't been measured and laid out on the screen yet. `ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal` needs the target view to be measured to calculate the animation. You'll also find that your variables `a` and `b` are always 0.

If you want to experiment, create the animation and start it within a button click listener. Here's an example using your code:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        int a = (tv.getLeft() + tv.getRight()) / 2;
        int b = (tv.getTop() + tv.getBottom()) / 2;

        int radius = tv.getWidth();

        Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(tv, a, b, 0, radius);

        anim.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use `Runnable` to do the animation. The `Runnable` will run after the view's creation. No need to post delay.

```
view.post(new Runnable()
{ 
       @Override 
       public void run(){ 
           //create your anim here
       } 
});
```

Comment: @TimoBähr can you post your log here in comment.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can do this.

```
 tv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                tv.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                tv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(tv, a, b, 0, radius);
            anim.start();
        }
    });
```

Adding GlobalLayoutListener to wait for the view to be inflated worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Or you can do this.

```
   tv.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //start your animation here                        
                    }
                }, 1000);
```

Comment: Does that work because it gives time to the View to be attached to the activity?

Comment: Yes as Rlay3 has mentioned